# Bind a event on change Angular-carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel

I am using [Angular carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) .  I need to bind a event on the change of A -> B, or B -> A

```
 <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-indicator rn-carousel-index="slideIndex" class="my-slider slider3 carousel-ui ng-cloak">
   <li><div class="big zone-area">A</div></li>
   <li><div class="big zone-area">B</div></li>
 </ul>
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you perhaps just [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) the index? Something like:

```
$scope.$watch('slideIndex', function (newIndex, oldIndex) {
    if (oldIndex === 0 && newIndex === 1) {
        // A -> B
    }
    else if (oldIndex === 1 && newIndex === 0) {
        // B -> A
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing this approach working: http://jsfiddle.net/8c6UG/2/

Comment: well, the $watch is not trigerring when i am toggling, any clue?

Comment: @RichardTowers, the fiddle seems to be not working, can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. It seems something changed in one of the external files I had linked to. I've switched to the canonical URLs in http://jsfiddle.net/8c6UG/2/ which fixes the issue.